# Джеммер - одна или две "м"?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, удвоенные-буквы

Совместная импровизация нескольких музыкантов называется "джем", от английского "jam". Участник джема соответственно *джеммер* или *джемер*. Подскажите, как правильно.

Answer (score 1):

По-английски — jammer. Зачем выбрасывать одну букву "м"?. Аналог — диггер, а не дигер.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы произносите с удвоенным звуком "м", то через "мм".

Answer (score 0):

Думаю,  джемер. Хотя благозвучнее с 2 м.

Answer (score 0):

Можно как джеммер, так и джаммер. Второе, правда, более к технике употребимо, но суть одна и та же - "несколько источников". Все дело в неоднозначности переложения на русский звука "a" в данном случае. Поэтому и получаются "Макс Джеммер", но "базовые параметры джаммеров".